Нужна ли запятая при приложении перед именем собственным?
«Ради своего сына, Павла Власова, она терпит...»

Запятая ставится:
Ради своего сына, Павла Власова, она терпит...
Пояснение
В общем случае возможны варианты (определительное или уточняющее значение), но здесь надо выбрать уточнение. Важно, что ради сына, а имя дается как дополнительная информация.
Кроме того, при отсутствии обособления можно подумать, что у матери есть и другие сыновья, но в данном случае речь идет именно о Павле.
